# Dont get style of div in print using CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css

I want to print content in a div using Javascript and CSS. My main div is with id 'preview'. Content in a div taken from database using PHP and MySQL. In my print page don't get style of the div 'preview'. I want to open print screen in new window. Any body give any suggestion for these issue?

My page and print are

[image]

[image]

My code is given below.

```
     <?php
 error_reporting(0);
 $host='localhost'; // Host Name.
 $db_user= 'root'; //User Name
 $db_password= '';
 $db= 'excel'; // Dat
 $conn=@mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
 $sql = "select * from first order by id";
 $rsd = @mysql_query($sql);
 ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function printDiv(divID)
   {
        var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = 
          "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
          divElements + "</body>";
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
   }


 </script>
 <style type="text/css" media="print">
 @media print{ #preview{ height:100%;overflow:visible;} } 
 </style>
  <style>

  #my-list{

  padding: 10px;
  padding-left:15px;
  width:auto;
 margin:auto;
  }
 #my-list > li {
display: inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
  }
 #my-list > li > a{
color: #666666;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 3px 8px;
 }
 </style>

  <input type="button" value="Print" onClick="javascript:printDiv('preview')" />
   <div id="preview" style="width:1000px; margin:auto;">
 <ul id="my-list" >

    <?php  



    $si=1;

    while($fet=mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
    {
        ?>
             <li> 



            <div class="droppable2"  style="border-color:#3300FF; border:solid #999999;  
            height:180px;width:180px;position:relative; " >
            <div style="float:left;position:absolute; bottom:30px;" class="left">

             <img  src="img.png" >

            </div>
            <div style="float:right;">
            <p style="color: #003399;  font-size: 10px;
             padding-right:5px; font-weight:800; ">www.selafone.net</p>
             <table style="font-size:10px;" >
             <tr> <td >USERNAME: </td> <td> <?php echo $fet['name']; ?> </td></tr>
              <tr> <td>PASSWORD:</td> <td> <?php echo $fet['email']; ?></td></tr></table>
            </div>
             <div  style="position:absolute;background-color:#FF0000;
              padding-bottom:0px; bottom: 0;   height:36px;  ">
              <div style="color:#FFFFFF; padding-left:30px; vertical-align:middle;
              font-weight:100;padding-top:10px; font-size: 8px;">
              <strong> International prepaid Calling Card</strong></div></div>
              </div>
          </li>
        <?php   
        $si=$si+1;  
        }

      ?>

      </ul>

     </div>
```

Comment: Normally, browsers will hide the background colors when printing. The reason is that if you had a background color on your entire site, printing would print the background color on the entire page, using a ton of ink and not looking very good. I can't remember off the top of my head how to make it print the background colors, so consult Google for that.

Comment: Read this thread, it will help explain: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7090451/259457

Comment: @ Travesty3 I got the background color :),you know how open these window in new page?

Answer (score 0):

Source: [Background color not showing in print preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987496/background-color-not-showing-in-print-preview)

---

> this is copy/paste reply of @purgatory101 from the top url

---

"

The Chrome css property "-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;" works appropriately.

However, making sure you have the correct css for printing can often be tricky. Several things can be done to avoid the difficulties you are having. First, separate all your print css from your screen css. This is done via the @media print and @media screen.

Often times just setting up some extra @media print css is not enough because you still have all your other css included when printing as well. In these cases you just need to be aware of css specificity as the print rules don't automatically win against non-print css rules.

In your case, the -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact is working. However, your background-color and color definitions are being beaten out by other css with higher specificity.

While I DO NOT endorse using !important in nearly any circumstance, the following definitions work properly and expose the problem:

```
@media print {
  .your_id {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #1a4567 !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
  }
}
```

"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open new window with printing page you need to create this window. Something like this:

```
function printDiv(divID)
{
    var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML; // your div
    var newWindow=window.open('','','width=600,height=600');    // new window
    newWindow.document.write(divElements);                      // div → window
    newWindow.document.close();
    newWindow.focus();
    newWindow.print();                                          // printing
    newWindow.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your CSS rules like this:

```
@media screen {
    // css rules for screen
} 

@media print {
    // css rules for print
}
```

Comment: My main div 'preview' contain innner div and paragraphp.I added all styles to @media print {
    
} ,But dont get style