Printing removed background from table cells
I currently did not understand what happened, because it worked before
I Have this HTML
                            <td bgcolor="#99ffff" width="75%">
                                <div class="text-left">
                                    <p>
                                        I.01 - TERAS  DAN KANTIN
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text-right">
                                    <p>
                                        Kayu                                              
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>

Which shows in the browser

But now, when Print Invoked via browser
the background (blue color) vanish

Any Idea ?
Check different browser

Firefox
Brave

Check printer setting for make sure it's in color

Browsers often remove backgrounds when printing, look for "More Options" and enable "Print Backgrounds" checkbox

Here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090451/html-css-why-background-color-turns-white-when-printing

the thing is, it was worked just until yesterday.
And its not just real printing,
Print as PDF also remove the BGColor

As I said, it's a browser checkbox
